# InputStream from a local file VB.net

Tags: .net, vb.net, inputstream, fileinputstream

I'm trying to upload a file to a web with an API service but I can't pass a local file to `InputStream`.

How can I do it? I use a `FileWebRequest` but doesn't work.

```
Dim uri As New Uri("C:/Captura.PNG")
Dim myFileWebRequest As FileWebRequest = WebRequest.Create(uri)
Dim myFileWebResponse As FileWebResponse = myFileWebRequest.GetResponse()
Dim receiveStream As Stream = myFileWebResponse.GetResponseStream()
```

Comment: First tenet to ask questions. Show the code you have written so far and show where you have problems.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't get local file via http.
Use [`File.Open`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b9skfh7s.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) method:

```
Dim fs As FileStream = File.Open("C:/Captura.PNG", _
        FileMode.Open, _
        FileAccess.Write, _
        FileShare.None)
```

Since `FileStream` is `Stream`, you'll get your file.

Comment: I tried this but not works. However I have another problem because I need to pass this Stream to string because API requires this.

Comment: @n26 What string do you need? With contents? What didn't work? What the exception?

Comment: I use an API service that requires the parameters file (InputStream), fileName (string) and length (long). But these parameters are stored in a dictionary (string, string) to send to the API. There is no exception, but not upload the file.

Comment: @n26 So you don't want the Stream - just the file name. Pass the `Captura.PNG` there, when uploading the `Captura.PNG` file. Check the API logs for the error. Can't say much more about your issue.